# Is it possible to use .jar outside of "war" directory?

Tags: tomcat, gwt

I´m wondering if I can use a .jar archive on the GWT server-side that is available on the server but not in WEB-INF/lib directory.

Usually you put your .jar in the lib folder and add it to the classpath. But if the .jar is already on the server do I have to duplicate it?

Or is there any configuration possibility to avoid that?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is it on the server? Is it part of the servlet container's own classpath, or is it just sitting in some other directory somewhere? Are you just trying to save a little bit of space, or are you trying to ensure something specific about this other file?

Comment: Actually it´s outside of the CATALINA_HOME directory.
It´s a set of jars what makes copying seem a little awkward to me... 
Already tried with linux ln -s but tomcat is too smart.

Comment: Okay, so that's another grain of the 'what', now how about the 'why'? If you want to save 1mb of space, there are almost certainly better ways around this that don't add potential security risks or require brittle code in your war: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Sry Colin, I edited my comment - but too slow:
It´s a set of jars what makes copying seem a little awkward to me... Already tried with linux ln -s but tomcat is too smart.

Comment: Can you clarify about 'too smart'? Is it skipping soft links because it interprets them as a security problem (and so you can cheat and turn that off? Have you considered a hard link? And once again, *why* do you want to do this? Is there a good reason you don't simply put the jar in the web-inf/lib/ where it belongs?

Comment: I wanted to keep this question as generic as possible - but here´s my story:
I´ve set up a Hadoop environment which brings its own Tomcat Server and now im making experiments on deploying Web Applications that use the Hadoop-Libraries. 
The Tomcat is in hadoop_home/share/hadoop/httpfs/tomcat and the jars I want to use are already in hadoop_home/share/hadoop/* so copying it just some subdirectories "further down" seems not right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found this [link](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath) with a very good explanation.

If anybody has the same issue - in case of a GWT WebApp I recommend:

1. Write the GWT App as usual, copy the required *.jar* files to
   *WEB-INF/lib* directory and add it to the Classpath (to avoid errors and make it compile properly)
2. When deploying the app, just don´t copy the *.jar* files that are already on the server to *WEB-INF/lib*
3. Edit the ***catalina.properties*** file in *tomcat_root/conf*. Add the fully qualified paths comma separated to the ***shared.loader*** property (which initially should be empty)
4. Restart Tomcat and smile!

But: Be aware that WebApps are meant to be self-contained. Changing the *shared.loader* property makes the *.jar* files visible to any WebApp on Tomcat. This might cause namespace conflicts or be inappropriate because of security reasons.